# usort comparison function does not appear to be called

Tags: php, usort

I have an array with objects and I want to sort the array by an object property. So I have to use usort for that. But my array keeps unsorted. So *I put some var_dumps to my code to debug it*. Here is my code:

```
var_dump(count($fields));
usort($fields, function ($a, $b) {
    var_dump("A");
    return ($b->getPosition() - $a->getPosition());
});
var_dump("B");
die;
```

The result is this: `int(4) string(1) "B"`, and..

*I expect to see `string(1) "A"` printed as well*

So it appears that nothing happens inside the usort function. What might explain this behavior? My PHP Version is 7.1.21

**(I have edited the code above, but it's still not working. There is no A logged and the array is not sorted)**

Comment: Do `var_dump($fields)` and post the output

Comment: var_dump($fields);die; gives me an empty page... But var_dump($fields[0]->getPosition());die; gives me the correct number.

Comment: Well, that's strange. What about `var_dump(gettype($fields))` then?

Comment: Thats string(6) "object"

Comment: If var_dump($fields) give you an empty page... maybe the problem you are looking is not on the usort, but in the assignation/declaration/modification of this array, so we'll need to see that code.. I tried your code with an array defined by myself and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usort` doesn't work with objects (in PHP 7.2 anyway). You need to convert that to array (as it seems to be a collection object, it likely has a method like `toArray()`)